# Things to take care before installing wordpress Manual v/s Softaculous

Tags: installation

I have cleared up the [first step](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58326/things-to-take-care-when-moving-from-hosted-wordpress-to-self-hosting)  on moving to Self-hosted wordpress.
Now I have a confusion if someone can answer:

1: My hosting provider's tutorial shows installing WP from cPanel using tool called Softaculous. Is it a good way to use that utility or do by grabbing the wp package from wordpress.org and do everything manually? I tried and it was easy but want to know pros/cons.

Using Softaculos I am confused with the two things:

a: Choose protocol: It has options:  `http://, http://www, https:// and https://www`
I know my site isn't using ssl so now what should I choose `http:// or http://www`
And why should I chose one over other?

b: In Directory: Asking me where should I install it? in the root or sub-directory e.g. `http://mydomain/wp` What should I choose there? And why?

Primary purpose of my site is I will be blogging. In future I don't know what it could turn out? If I install it in say a sub-directory say root/wp, I found that I can set the Site Address(Url) from WP Admin panel.

I want to do it right in terms of SEO rankings, maintenance and future changes.

Any explanation / suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how this is a "specific-to-WordPress" problem.

Comment: Sorry, if I had that much understanding, I would have asked in right place. So you can migrate it to other appropriate section if it doesn't fit here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your already confused with using Softaculos why not go with the file source from wordpress.org which has a very very simple installtion that takes just a minute or two. You simply need to create your database, user and enter that when installing WordPress.

You can set the www or non-www in WordPress itself during installation.

If you install it in your root directory that means WordPress will be your main site www.example.com otherwise if it's in a folder such as /blog now only www.example.com/blog is WordPress. So if you want your entire site powered by WordPress you must install it in your root folder.

You can install on your main site power it by WordPress and still have /blog as a page with a blog template. In my opinion it's much better to have it in the root folder and power your site with WordPress it's so much easier to manage and customize.

Comment: Thanks. From you explanation, whichever way I go I will face same questions(i)I should go with www or non-www and why (ii) root v/s subdirectory. I want to know how things matter in terms of search engine and best practices.

Comment: In terms of SEO it doesn't matter. Look at digg.com they force non-www. While other sites force www. Sub-folder or subdomain doesn't matter either Matt Cutts has said this in a number of videos.

Comment: Anagio, I think you can revise your answer in light of this [Codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Step_4:_Upload_the_files). Also, this looks like the perfect case to mention, cite and point the OP to the official documentation. Regards,